# Sending OpenCV2 Videowrite input to buffer instead of file

Tags: python, opencv, memory

I would like to write openCV2 videorecorder output to a buffer in the memory rather than to a file on my hard drive.  Following that i could write out to a file or not (and this way save a flash based object from over use).  I've tried pyfilesystem and i've tried things like IO and StringIO, but VideoRecorder does not accept these saying it was looking for a String or Unicode type and instead found a (_IOTextWrapper, IOString, etc....) type.

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm miss-understanding you or I'm just not knowledgeable enough so I don't understand the problem. But what you want to do is send a buffer object to VideoCapture so it's in the memory not HDD? I'm not finding any VideoRecorder object in cv2. If that's the case, that it's VideoCapture, then you can easily make your own buffer object, or just store the frames in a list and pop if from time to time.

Comment: @ljetibo  below is the description for the videowriter.  the 1st arg is for a filename where the frames will be written to make a video.  I want to write these to the memory, and only store them in a file on the drive if they contain something I want.  However, all my attempts have failed becuase the fuction appears to have a very specific type it will write to. http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#videowriter-videowriter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get now what you mean, however that would somehow tend to break the purpose of VideoWriter I suppose. It's job is to *write* the video on the disk. However, I agree, it would be nice to have a Video class that then we could manipulate within cv2.

Meanwhile, lucky for us, video's are nothing but sequences of frames, which are but numpy arrays. We can do a lot with those so here's the general idea I'd propose:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

def save_to_vid(video):
    path = ".../output.avi"
    height , width , layers =  video[0].shape
    out = cv2.VideoWriter(path, cv2.cv.FOURCC("X", "V", "I", "D"),
                          20.0, (width, height))
    for frame in frames:
        out.write(frame)

    out.release()


##CAPTURING SOME TEST FRAMES
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
frames = list() #THIS IS YOUR VIDEO
while(cap.isOpened()):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if ret==True:
        frame = cv2.flip(frame,0)
        frames.append(frame)

        cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break
    else:
        break
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

#SOMETIMES LATER IN THE RPOGRAM
doYouWantToSave = True
if doYouWantToSave:
    save_to_vid(frames)
else:
    del frames
```

Of course this all can be done smarter I suppose by creating your own class Video and then instantiating that and handling it as an object in your code. Video could have a method "writeToFile" as well. It could even be scripted a bit smarter to save some space, or work as an actual buffer if that's exactly what you need.

Comment: ha, I was almost there and didn't ever know it, I just couldn't think of what the 'frame' was to think of a memory container to put it in!  Only took changing about 3 lines of code.  Thank you very much!

Comment: hello can i use appsink in videowriter directly

Comment: Keep in mind that you are storing raw frames.. at least you can encode them into jpeg or something before.. Video encoders such as H265 are much more efficient. So stroting list of frames is not equal to encoding video into memory buffer